# Problem in uninstalling ubuntu 12.04

Tags: uninstall

I installed ubuntu 12.04 using wubi. But there is no application named " uninstall-ubuntu ". Now how can I uninstall it ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you completely install ubuntu onto another partition or did you just install it within windows? If you just installed it within windows you should be able to go to "Programs and Features" in the control panel, find Ubuntu and uninstall it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a Windows question than Ubuntu. It's like "How can I remove a Windows application ? " because wubi is exactly this. A Windows application - helper to install Ubuntu **inside** Windows. More like a fake installation (at my opinion).

So open Windows Control Panel, locate the wubi application and uninstall it.